# Odd behavior with Semantic-UI and meteor

Tags: meteor, semantic-ui

The is a meteorpad at http://meteorpad.com/pad/hiEWsbkrBjLvwgx5t/Semantic-UI%20Meteor which is using Meteor amd Semantic-UI. It pretty much works as expected except for the white bar at the top of the window that turns black when you click the "Open Sidebar" button and then stays black whether the sidebar is open or not. An inspect element on that "bar" points to the  tag. Anyone have any idea what causes this or how to address it?

TIA!

Answer (score 0):

OK... here is a fully working example of an off canvas mobile menu using Meteor with Semantic-UI. Pop out the browser Window and resize to the the changes. It could be tweaked with media queries, but to keep it simple, I just used Semantics defaults... http://meteorpad.com/pad/C3PWfMDoG3jPF2tC8/Semantic%20UI%20mobile%20nav%20sample